# Combine array and MySQL results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a quiz that uses an array to store the questions:

```
$array=array(
        '1'=> array('1','What does everyone know when they see it?','quest1','Good     publicity','Bad punctuation', 'Good business writing', 'Bad spelling','../images/example03.jpg'),
        '2'=> array('2','What do people write instead of \'now\'?','quest2','Presently','At this moment in time', 'Currently', 'At the present time','../images/example03.jpg'),
);
```

I then display the questions using this loop:

```
foreach($array as $quiz)
{
echo            
                '<div class="question">
                        <div class="questionList">
                            <h4>' . $quiz[0] . '. <strong>' . $quiz[1] .         '</strong></h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><input type="radio" name="' . $quiz[2] . '" value="1"> '. $quiz[3] . '</li>
                                    <li><input type="radio" name="' . $quiz[2] . '" value="2"> '. $quiz[4] . '</li>
                                    <li><input type="radio" name="' . $quiz[2] . '" value="3"> '. $quiz[5] . '</li>
                                    <li><input type="radio" name="' . $quiz[2] . '" value="4"> '. $quiz[6] . '</li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                    <img src="'. $quiz[7] . '" class="questionImg01" />
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                </div>
                ';
    }

}
```

If someone doesn't answer all the questions the first time, I store the values for each question in MySQL or "0" if there was no answer. I would like to check the radio buttons that the user has already answered, but can't work out how to combine the quiz array and the MySQL results.

The table structure for the results is:

quiz_id | username | quest1 | quest2 | quest3 | quest4 | quest5 | quest6 | quest7 | quest8 | quest9 | quest10 | complete

Where quiz_id is the reference number for that quiz and complete is a flag to record if the user has answered all the questions. I'm retrieving the results like this:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz_results_baseline WHERE username = ('$username')");
```

Is there a way I can combine these two?

I also have the problem where I can't make this query include a WHERE statement - I would like to store all the quiz results in one table and then refer to each user's quiz results using the quiz_id:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO quiz_results_baseline (quest1,quest2,quest3,quest4,quest5,quest6,quest7,quest8,quest9,quest10,username,quiz_id,complete) VALUES $queryData ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quest1=VALUES(quest1),quest2=VALUES(quest2),quest3=VALUES(quest3),quest4=VALUES(quest4),quest5=VALUES(quest5),quest6=VALUES(quest6),quest7=VALUES(quest7),quest8=VALUES(quest8),quest9=VALUES(quest9),quest10=VALUES(quest10),complete=VALUES(complete)");
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Was my answer helpful or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get your half completed quiz results to render along with the quiz, try the following code.

```
$questions=array(
  '1'=> array('1','What does everyone know when they see it?','quest1','Good     publicity','Bad punctuation', 'Good business writing', 'Bad spelling','../images/example03.jpg'),
  '2'=> array('2','What do people write instead of \'now\'?','quest2','Presently','At this moment in time', 'Currently', 'At the present time','../images/example03.jpg'),
);

// do your query for the row of answers
// $answers = mysql_fetch_assoc(...);

// for testing
$answers = array(
 'quest1' => '1',
 'quest2' => '4');


for($i = 1; $i <= count($questions); $i++)
{
  $quiz = $questions[$i];
  $answer = $answers[$quiz[2]];

  echo            
    '<div class="question">
        <div class="questionList">
          <h4>' . $quiz[0] . '. <strong>' . $quiz[1] . '</strong></h4>
          <ul>
            <li><input type="radio" name="' . $quiz[2] . '" value="1" ' . (($answer == '1') ? 'checked' : '') . '> '. $quiz[3] . '</li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="' . $quiz[2] . '" value="2" ' . (($answer == '2') ? 'checked' : '') . '> '. $quiz[4] . '</li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="' . $quiz[2] . '" value="3" ' . (($answer == '3') ? 'checked' : '') . '> '. $quiz[5] . '</li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="' . $quiz[2] . '" value="4" ' . (($answer == '4') ? 'checked' : '') . '> '. $quiz[6] . '</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <img src="'. $quiz[7] . '" class="questionImg01" />
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
    ';
}
```

You will have to do your query to get the `$answers` array, but I put in an example so you can see how to use the result.

I ran the code and the results looks like this:

[image: results]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you - this is great. Do you know how to make this query specific to username and quiz_id: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO quiz_results_baseline (quest1,quest2,quest3,quest4,quest5,quest6,quest7,quest8,quest9,quest10,username,quiz_id,complete) VALUES $queryData ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quest1=VALUES(quest1),quest2=VALUES(quest2),quest3=VALUES(quest3),quest4=VALUES(quest4),quest5=VALUES(quest5),quest6=VALUES(quest6),quest7=VALUES(quest7),quest8=VALUES(quest8),quest9=VALUES(quest9),quest10=VALUES(quest10),complete=VALUES(complete)");`

Comment: Glad that worked! You should post a new questions to get this answered. When you post it, describe your table structure and more about what you are trying to do. I don't quite understand based on just seeing that query.